# MouseLeftButtonUp : exactly fire condition?

Tags: windows-phone-8, interaction, mouseleftbuttonup

I have got some Rectangles, what I'm trying to implement is:

user touch the screen, he could slide between Rectangles. then his finger Lift off, and the last touched rectangle is selected.
(Lift off outside rectangle will trigger nothing)

Just like my lumia 920's keyboard, once you recognized that your finger was in a wrong place, you could slide to the right place, lift off, and the right character show on the screen.

many thanks to you heroes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's trickier than it seems, as the MouseLeftButtonUp event will be triggered only if the MouseLeftButtonDown has first been triggered on the control.

I see two ways to achieve this result:

1. Assign the same MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp event handler to all your rectangles. In the MouseLeftButtonDown, call the `CaptureMouse` method (it tells the control to continue tracking the mouse events even if the cursor isn't on top of the control anymore):

   ```
   private void MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       ((UIElement)sender).CaptureMouse();
   }
   ```

   In the MouseLeftButtonDown, release the mouse, then use the `VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates` to find the rectangle on which the cursor was when the even was triggered:

   ```
   private void MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       var element = (UIElement)sender;

       element.ReleaseMouseCapture();

       var mouseUpRectangle = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(e.GetPosition(this), this.ContentPanel)
           .OfType<Rectangle>()
           .FirstOrDefault();

       if (mouseUpRectangle != null)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("MouseUp in " + mouseUpRectangle.Name);
       }
   }
   ```

   (replace ContentPanel by the name of the container in which you've put all your controls)
2. Not tested but it might work. Subscribe to the MouseLeftButtonUp event of the container in which you've put all your rectangles. Then use the same logic to retrieve the rectangle at the coordinates of the pointer:

   ```
   private void MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {                
       var mouseUpRectangle = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(e.GetPosition(this), this.ContentPanel)
           .OfType<Rectangle>()
           .FirstOrDefault();

       if (mouseUpRectangle != null)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine("MouseUp in " + mouseUpRectangle.Name);
       }
   }
   ```

You can find more information in [that article](http://blogs.codes-sources.com/kookiz/archive/2012/01/08/wp7-how-to-press-the-mouse-on-a-control-and-detect-mouseleftbuttonup-on-another.aspx) I wrote a few months ago.

Comment: Generally it works, there seem to be many strange behavior about Mouse

Comment: but two more problems generated : 1. after MouseCapture, MouseEnter won't work during sliding,  2. each tap operation will trigger MouseLeftButtonUP 2 times...

Comment: Have you tried the second solution? It doesn't use MosueCapture, so it may solve the MouseEnter issue